# How does Prince Thorald works when fighting together?

Tags: legends-of-andor

From page 7 of the rulebook:

> When Prince Thorald is standing on the same space as a creature, he adds 4 extra strength points to the hero’s points in a battle.

I can interpret this in two different ways if several heroes fight together:

1. The Prince adds 4 extra strength to the group as a whole.
2. The Prince adds 4 extra strength to each hero in the fight. So if 3 heroes are in the fight, the Prince adds 12 extra strenght in total.

Which one is correct? I would assume it's the first, but the French version of the rulebook is even more ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Page 2 of the [Reference Rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/legends-of-andor/Preview%20Images/ANDOR_Reference.pdf)

> If an ally occupies the same space as a monster, it adds four to the
> final battle value against that monster.

**So your option 1 is correct.**

> The Prince adds 4 extra strength to the group as a whole.

I do agree the language is ambiguous and I would have tended towards option 2 from reading just of that rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was driving me crazy! This is indeed less ambiguous than the French version which could easily be interpreted both ways.

Comment: @Eldy The French translation is riddled with ambiguous wordings that are outright wrong if read literally. When in doubt, I advise you to choose the more natural / logical / thematic interpretation.